# How are configuration files read from /etc/sysctl.d/ directory?

Tags: security, centos7, coredump, hardening

I was reading the CIS CentOS Linux 7 Benchmark v.2.2.0, section-1.5.1(Ensure core dumps are restricted). Its remediation sections says:

> Add the following line to /etc/security/limits.conf or a **/etc/security/limits.d/***
> file:
>
> - hard core 0

I have a remediation script to achieve the same (got from github). Its contents are :

```
echo "hard core 0" >> /etc/security/limits.d/CIS.conf
echo "fs.suid_dumpable = 0" >> /etc/sysctl.d/CIS.conf
```

My question is -> Why is the script adding the lines in CIS.conf. I know it is not a system conf file. So how does the OS know to read this conf file? Is it that the OS reads from all conf files present under the /etc/sysctl.d/ path?

Comment: Yes. 

"
...
/etc/sysctl.d/*.conf
...

At boot, systemd-sysctl.service(8) reads configuration files from the above directories to configure sysctl(8) kernel parameters."


https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sysctl.d.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @inverzeio !! that cleared my confusion well.